# Update Route Tables on Windows Mobile 5 or 6

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-ce, ipv4

Anyone know how to show and update the routing table on Windows Mobile (like you would with the route utility on Windows)?

My first choice would be a utility, second choice would be C# code, third choice C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found a nice little shareware app that let us do everything we needed at http://www.z2software.com/PocketLAN.htm.

Comment: nice little tool, and so worth the $15

Answer (score 1):

Something [along these lines](http://blog.opennetcf.com/2008/02/15/sdf-sample-device-network-routing-table/)?  Under the hood it calls things like [GetIpForwardTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450412.aspx) and [CreateIpForwardEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms887916.aspx).

Comment: Chris, thanks! We found a utility to get us by, but may use the SDF code if we need to call it programatically.

Comment: Hi @ctacke, your first link is dead, do you know how to retrieve it ?